# Connecting to existing collection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to node.js and mongoose and trying to access an existing collection in MongoDB Atlas named 'questions' inside a database called 'database'

i was able to do that using the MongoDB native driver as:

```
MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true },(err,client)=>{
    assert.equal(null,err);
    var db = client.db('database')
    const collection = db.collection('questions');
    collection.findOne({},(err,docs)=>{
        assert.equal(null,err);
        console.log("found");
        console.log(docs);
        client.close();
    })
})
```

but can't seem to make it work using mongoose to do the same task of using findOne() from the mongodb collection:

```
mongoose.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open',()=>{
    console.log("connected")
})

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({},{strict:false})

const question = mongoose.model("question",questionSchema,"questions")

const getone =async ()=>{
    const post = await question.findOne({})
    console.log(post)
}

getone()
```

when i run this, the console output is :

[image]

How can i access this collection from mongoose

Thank you

Comment: check you database  name in connection string. it should start with lower case

Answer (score 1):

```
const getone =async ()=>{
    const post = await db.collection(<collectionName>).findOne({});
    console.log(post)
}
```

You can try in this way, it worked for me!
See the documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-collection)

Comment: Please write a brief summary of the content of the link you provide. Remember that such content may no longer be available at later. Read [answer].